# Including PDF into pdflatex document

Tags: graphics, pdftex

Trying to include a raster graphic into my document. From what I have read, EPS isn't supported with pdflatex, and pdf should be the prefered format for doing so. From what I understand, the following should work (complete example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{chart.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But `pdflatex` gives me the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .pdf.
```

Complete output is:

```
[root@trendline perfrep]# pdflatex example
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(./pdftex.def))) (./example.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .pdf.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Comment: Omit the `.pdf` extension, but that's only a guess

Comment: It says "File 'chart' not found" when I do.

Comment: Try to call `pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex`, where `foo` is the name of your tex file.

Comment: It seems to be a Unix/Linux installation. Does it recognize *.PDF (uppercase latters) extension?

Comment: Shell escape and uppercase make no difference

Comment: Taking Heiko Oberdiek's answer into account: Again my suggestion: Update to TeXLive 2015

Comment: \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg,.jpeg}
works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pdftex.def` in the current directory is wrong (outdated, broken, not a graphics driver file at all, ...). Move the file out of the way and the correct 
file `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def` should be found and used.

The supported bitmap image formats of pdfTeX in PDF mode are PNG, JPEG, and JBIG2. Of course, bitmaps in PDF also work.

Comment: My /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/ directory is empty. a yum search of pdftext.def returns no results. I am susspecting a distribution problem? I just installed today. You know where I can get the file from?

Comment: @Brad The file is also available in CTAN: [CTAN:macros/latex/contrib/pdftex-def/pdftex.def](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdftex-def/pdftex.def). `texhash` or `mktexlsr` should be called after installation to update the file name data base, for example: `texhash /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist`.

Comment: Awesome - totally works after downloading that file. Thanks!